# UITableView change detailText on already created cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableView, to which I add cells via UIButton. On creation the cell gets its `textLabel` & `detailTextLabel` from 2 arrays. However, if an item with the same Title already exists in the table, I want to change the `detailTextLabel.text` of the existing cell without adding a new cell.

So is there a way to update the detailText of a certain `UITableViewCell` when it was already created with some value?

Maybe I should just remove the old one and add new?

Comment: You can retain a reference to the cell that you wish to modify (then modify it when you wish), just like any other control, or you can recreate your cell with the updated data.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing -- you don't normally "add cells" to a table, you add data to the array populating the table, and you get more rows automatically. I think you need to show your code, so we can see how you're populating your table.

Comment: cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellID];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating of a UITableView cell should be just that, creation and not population of data, since we re use cells we should always assume the cell data is stale and needs a refresh, therefore you should always have a way to reset the values of the cells, if you have a custom cell you should expose the controls you are using and set their values accordingly in cellForRowAtIndexPath, if you require to change a cell you should either change the data source values and reload the cell via `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` , or grab a hold of the cell with cellForRowAtIndexPath and change the values accordigly... my point is no need to recreate the cell..